# WPF textBox changes color halfway

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textblock

I have a strange problem with the textBox in WPF. I have a simple textbox inside a stackpanel binded with some text on the code behind. When the text becomes too long some part of it changes color. Here is an example

[image]

The stackpanel is this

```
    <StackPanel Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="111">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#9EA3AA"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

How can I make all the text white?

Comment: The panel on the right apparently overlays the text with its semi-transparent background. Consider implementing a proper layout for your view, instead of putting everything in a Canvas with absolute positioning.

Comment: I need the canvas in this particual case because I need control over the position of the single pixel for something I should implement later. But that's not the problem since removing every other panel on the canvas other that the stack panel doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Could you please post enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Clemens you were right I was experiencing overlapping but with something that was hidden from before, that's why I didn't noticed. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Clemens you are experiencing overlap. To fix this make the cell containing the orange cpu image and text not extend so high. You should be able to just drag and drop.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think is that. I  even tried commenting the entire list containing the CPU image to make sure it doesn't appear but the weird color glitch persists

Comment: Edit: nevermind you were right. I was experiencing overlapping but with an element that I forgot was there since was hidden. Thank you